# Storing Facebook Post id

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I'm trying to delete a post on a Facebook page using Facebook api.

I have the id stored in the mysql database as a varchar with 40 length.

This is the code I am using

```
        $access_token =  $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
        $response = $facebook->api(
        $post_id,
        'DELETE' 
        );
```

When I get the id and make it equal `$post_id`, and then try to delete the post I get an error.

Although if I make `$post_id = 575757574757_575757579888` then it deletes the post.

So what I'm saying is that if `$post_id` equal the value retrieved from the mysql database then the delete request doesn't work. If a manually make `$post_id` equal the post id that I copied and pasted from the database manually, then it work.

So I am thinking that the value retrieved or stored in he database might be in the wrong format for Facebook to recognise it.

I have done some prior research, and have echoed the value from the database and it looks correct.

This is how I am retrieving the string from my mysql database.

```
$ad_id = osc_ad_id();
$conn = getConnection();
$get_id=$conn->osc_dbFetchResult("SELECT * FROM %st_post_id WHERE ad_id = '$ad_id'", DB_TABLE_PREFIX);
$post_id = $get_id['post_id'];
```

Comment: Did your app create the post?

Comment: Yes, my app created the post and the id was returned and stored.

Answer (score -1):

Dump the id you get from database. If the variable is a string, you may need to transfer it to integer first.

Comment: "*I have done some prior research, and have echoed the value from the database and it looks correct.*"

Comment: @眺望地球 Hi, I have updated the question, and added the code that I use to get the id. What code would you like?